Having trouble decrypting v20 cookies
I am working on a cookie manager and had a few questions to ask about v20 encryption which is sooner rather than later gonna be rolled out all over chromium based browsers, i have recently tried injecting into chrome and i find an solution to get around it freezing everytime but im not sure what google means by a few things, questions will be below.
Will you have to decrypt v20 under the same pid or application name?
Are there any more requirements on top of the regular v10 encryption?

Starting from Chrome 127 released in July 2024, Google has introduced measures to protect cookies (and eventually other sensitive data) in Chrome from theft via infostealer malware. This means that only Chrome will be able to decrypt these new "v20" cookies.
The blogpost linked above goes into greater detail on how this is achieved, but in short, the key for sensitive data is governed by a service running as SYSTEM, and only applications that can identify themselves as Chrome (however they do so) will be able to obtain this key. Then, once obtained, the key is encrypted in memory. This means that malware can't request the key from the service because it can't identify as Chrome, nor can it read the encrypted key from memory.

could a program possibly inejct a dll into chrome to gain "application identity" and if so where could i read more on injecting into chrome without it freezing
